# Power shell User list variable

Tags: powershell

I need to add an Exchange license to a list of users using Power Shell.

I have created a little file to test with 3 users.

`users.txt`:
I added themn, one by one in three lines:

```
John F Stone
Peter Stewart Robinson
Mary Ann Daves
```

I created the variable:

```
$list = Get-Content 'D:\ListUsers.txt'
```

When I run the command:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Group Name" -User "$list" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

I receive this error message:

```
"Write-ErrorMessage : Ex9BC9DD|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundException|User or group "John F Stone
Peter Stewart Robinson
Mary Ann Daves" wasn't found. Please make sure you've typed it correctly."
```

If I add only one by in the txt file, it works.

Is there a right way to add users to the variable using the txt file?
Thank you.

Comment: You need a unique identifier for the user - not their legal/full name, but their _username_. In addition, you need to pass one user at a time: `$list |ForEach-Object { Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Group Name" -User $_ ... }`